# Why can we always find a $x$ for which that $px+a$ is always divisible by $b$?

Tags: divisibility

For any $p$ prime, $b \in \{1, ..., p-1\}$ and $a \in \mathbb{N}$,
why is there always a $x \in \mathbb{N_0}$ such that $b \mid px + a$?

Comment: It is not that $px+a$ is always divisible by $b$.  For most $x$ it won't be... but we will always be able to find one such that it is.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified the title.

Comment: Are you familiar with bezout's identity?  How about the euclidean division algorithm?  Quotient remainder theorem?

Comment: Suppose $px+a\equiv 0\pmod{b}$.  Then $px\equiv -a\pmod{b}$.  Now... to solve for $x$  if this were just a normal equality of real numbers, we'd say "divide both sides by $p$ to get $x=-\frac{a}{p}$", but its not a normal equation... it is a modular equivalence.  Are you aware of the fact that we can still "divide" though in modular equivalencies under the right circumstances (*by way of multiplicative inverses*)?  Does $p$ have a multiplicative inverse modulo $b$?  It should... because $p$ is prime.  How do we know what it is?  Bezouts identity and the extended euclidean division algorithm.

Comment: By the proof in the linked dupe: $\,px\equiv -a\pmod{\!b}\,$ has an integer root $x\iff \gcd(p,b)\mid a,\,$ which is true here since the gcd $=1.\,$ The root is $\,x\equiv -a/p \equiv -ap^{-1}\pmod{\!b},\,$ which can be computed by various methods linked there.